# Converting array of stringified key value pairs to hash in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, key-value

I have some key-value pair strings in an array:

```
array = [ "Name = abc", "Id = 123", "Interest = Rock Climbing" ]
```

I need to convert it to a hash:

```
hash = { "Name" => "abc", "Id" => "123", "Interest" => "Rock Climbing" }
```

I must be doing something wrong because I'm getting weird mappings with my `.shift.split` resulting in `{"Name=abc"=>"Id=123"}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need to do is split each part of the array into a key and value (yielding an array of two-element arrays) and then pass the result to the handy `Hash[]` method:

```
arr = [ "Name = abc", "Id = 123", "Interest = Rock Climbing" ]

keys_values = arr.map {|item| item.split /\s*=\s*/ }
# => [ [ "Name", "abc" ],
#      [ "Id", "123" ],
#      [ "Interest", "Rock Climbing" ] ]

hsh = Hash[keys_values]
# => { "Name" => "abc",
#      "Id" => "123",
#      "Interest" => "Rock Climbing" }
```

Comment: I tried with your above code, and it gives me below error

`wrong array length at 20 (expected 2, was 3)` Can anyone help me with resolving this. Also this same code is only not working for me in some rare case, however I don't see the difference in values for both working and not working cases.

Comment: @VinitSharma The `Hash[]` method expects data in pairs, i.e. an Array of Arrays of two elements each, like `[[key1, val1], [key2, val2], ...]`. The error is telling you that one of those Arrays has three elements instead of two.

Comment: Yes you are right, my source string was getting created incorrectly because of a single space with more than two elements. Got removed the white space and its working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way (using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)):

```
array.each_with_object({}) do |a, hash|
    key,value = a.split(/\s*=\s*/) # splitting the array items into key and value
    hash[key] = value    # storing key => value pairs in the hash
end
# => {"Name"=>"abc", "Id"=>"123", "Interest"=>"Rock Climbing"}
```

If you find it little difficult to understand the `each_with_object`, you can do it in a naive way (Just accumulating the `key` and `value`s in the `result_hash`):

```
result_hash = {}
array.each do |a|
    key,value = a.split(/\s*=\s*/) # splitting the array items into key and value
    result_hash[key] = value # storing key => value pairs in the result_hash
end
result_hash
# => {"Name"=>"abc", "Id"=>"123", "Interest"=>"Rock Climbing"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
array.map {|s| s.split('=')}.to_h

=> {"Name "=>" abc", "Id "=>" 123", "Interest "=>" Rock Climbing"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h.update([s.split(/\s*=\s*/)].to_h) }
  #=> {"Name"=>"abc", "Id"=>"123", "Interest"=>"Rock Climbing"}
```

For Ruby versions prior to 2.0 (when [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) was introduced) replace `[s.split(/\s*=\s*/)].h` with `Hash[[s.split(/\s*=\s*/)]]`.
The steps:

```
enum = array.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Name = abc", "Id = 123",
  #     "Interest = Rock Climbing"]:each_with_object({})>
```

We can see the elements of this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["Name = abc", {}], ["Id = 123", {}], ["Interest = Rock Climbing", {}]]
```

The first element of `enum` is passed to the block, the block variables are assigned:

```
s,h = enum.next
  #=> ["Name = abc", {}] 
s #=> "Name = abc" 
h #=> {}
```

and the block calculation is performed:

```
h.update([s.split(/\s*=\s*/)].to_h)
  #=> h.update([["Name", "abc"]].to_h) 
  #   {}.update({"Name"=>"abc"})
  #   {"Name"=>"abc"}
```

which is the updated value of `h`.

The next element of `enum` passed to the block is:

```
s,h = enum.next
  #=> ["Id = 123", {"Name"=>"abc"}] 
s #=> "Id = 123" 
h #=> {"Name"=>"abc"} 

h.update([s.split(/\s*=\s*/)].to_h)
  #=> {"Name"=>"abc", "Id"=>"123"}
```

and so on.